# When ever i open the Messenger app or the Facebook app, it instantly crashes my iPhone. What can I do to fix this? (iOS 11.3)

Tags: iphone, messages, crash, facebook

What can I do to fix this? I am using iOS 11.3.

Answer (score 2):

If it immediately crashes your system there are a couple of things you could do, starting with just powering the phone off and on again.

Failing that I would delete the app, reboot and reinstall it.